# How to store the entered data into a remote database?

Tags: android, sql, database, upload, sms

How to store the entered data into a remote database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to communicate with the remote server through API.To Send POST and GET request to the server, means to create a connection between the server and Android Application.There are many libraries to make `HTTP` request for example [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/),[Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) etc, These powerful libraries make it easy to consume JSON or XML data.You can send your data and store them in the remote database.

You can follow the tutorials for better understanding [link1](https://www.mytrendin.com/send-data-to-remote-server-in-android-using-volley-library/),[link2](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845).

Comment: Thanks for an info

Comment: //Add this line above Request queue...
       /*Your request name*/ `objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(3000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`

Comment: request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(3000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                queue.add(request);

Comment: You can increase the SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS i.e (3000) to 30000.